# What are some optical software packages (for windows) to design an optical experiment?

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, software

I need to design an optical experiment with laser beam using **beam splitter, mirror, quarter waveplate, polarizer and birefringent wedge**. I am looking for some optical software that has all or most of these elements. I checked some software packages but most of them only have mirrors and lenses. I want to do the real experiment after designing the arrangement in the software.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might be useful to list the packages you've found so users might exclude those from their searches.

Comment: I just looked for python tools and see a wide variety, but have no clue on how good any of them are...

Comment: Kind of like the optical calculus simulations  I do: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/666241/313612. My free software consists of add-ons to a commercial simulation program.

Comment: I’m voting to close this post (v4) because res. recom. qs on Phys.SE usually do not distinguish between free and non-free.

Comment: You might find something with GNU Octave and [packages](https://gnu-octave.github.io/packages/).

Comment: How could I improve the question? I removed "free" if that helps.

Comment: @Qmechanic:  it's moot now, because the criterion has been removed;  but why would asking for "free" resources make a difference?  To my eye it's just another criterion, like asking for a book published within the last 10 years.  It might limit the number of acceptable candidates but it doesn't make the question unanswerable.

Comment: Hi @Michael Seifert. Res. recom qs are restricted on Phys.SE, cf. various meta discussion.