# Formal proof that stacking multiple polarizers does/does not improve the extinction ratio?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, laser, polarization, calculus

Assume that you have a light source, e.g. a laser diode, with a [polarization extinction ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_ratio) (ER) of 100:1, and you need to improve the extinction ratio as much as possible by adding polarizers, e.g. [Glan-Taylor prisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glan%E2%80%93Taylor_prism) with an ER of 100000:1.

How can you mathematically prove, e.g. using [Stokes parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters) and [Müller calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mueller_calculus), that stacking multiple polarizers in equal orientation **will or will not** improve the final ER?

The ER can be measured by adding a rotatable polarizer, called *analyzer*, and measuring the optical power $P$ when the analyzer is adjusted to parallel ($0°$) and crossed ($90°$) orientation:

$$ ER = \tfrac{P_{max}}{P_{min}} = \tfrac{P(0°)}{P(90°)} $$

The analyzer can be assumed to be ideal, i.e. a perfect polarizer with an infinite ER.

```
  []----->-----[]----->-----[]----->-----[]     => Extinction ratio?
Source      Polarizer    Analyzer    Powermeter
(100:1)     (100000:1)   (ideal)


  []----->-----[]----->-----[]----->-----[]----->-----[]     => Extinction ratio?
Source      Polarizer    Polarizer    Analyzer    Powermeter
(100:1)     (100000:1)   (100000:1)   (ideal)


  []----->-----[]----->-----[]----->-----[]----->-----[]----->-----[]     => Extinction ratio?
Source      Polarizer    Polarizer    Polarizer    Analyzer    Powermeter
(100:1)     (100000:1)   (100000:1)   (100000:1)   (ideal)


                           etc.
```

Comment: A formal proof will be based on an idealized model, but you seem to be asking about an actual experimental situation. In the real world, you have to account for every significant leakage and scattering path. It's not the straight line you've drawn.

Comment: @JohnDoty I am indeed looking for a formal proof, disregarding any experimental realities such as reflection, absorption, scattering etc.! My main problem is to correctly express the finite extinction ratios e.g. in Stokes vectors and then run the mathematical machinery (probably a series of matrix multiplications) to see what is the result expected from theory.

Comment: ...for instance, you may assume the analyzer to be ideal, i.e. to be a perfect polarizer with an infinite extinction ratio. If you solve this problem for a single polarizer, the generalization to $N$ polarizers should be trivial.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be any more complicated than multiplying the ratios? That's how cascaded filters (ideally) work.

Comment: @JohnDoty Because I was told that stacking polarizers does *not* improve ER, which to me is counterintuitive. :) So I need to know what can be expected from theory, i.e. to see what is the correct answer *in principle*, and how experimental subleties may change the outcome (but that would probably be something for another question, now I only care about the theory).

Comment: I suggest you go ahead and ask that question if you want to understand what you have been told. Idealizations won't help you here.

Comment: @EdV Thanks, I'm curious what result you will get! Is it possible to try your software for free? Btw, not that I'm mainly interested in the correct formalism...once the maths is clear, I could also write e.g. a small Python script to simulate different scenarios.

Comment: @JohnDoty No, I want the theory first. Do you know the correct answer? If you have e.g. a perfectly unpolarized beam and add two polarizers with an ER of 1000 each, what result will you get: An ER closer to $1000$ or closer to $1000^2 = 1000000$? As you see from these numbers alone, this is not a question of experimental subtleties such as a 0.5% reflectance at some surface...this question should be perfectly decidable using e.g. Müller calculus. I'm just not familiar with the formalism yet

Comment: *In theory* the response of cascaded linear filters is their product. You're overthinking this.

Comment: @EdV Hey Ed, you posted an awesome link to your simulation, but it's gone now and I didn't have time to screenshot your calculations + explanations. It was super helpful, exactly what I was looking for...I just didn't have time yet to work through it carefully. Would you mind posting the results here or maybe send me the screenshot from your calculations? Thx a lot

Comment: @EdV Many thanks and no hurry! I thought I replied to you in a comment yesterday, but must have forgotten to send it - anyways, great to hear that you have updated results. This topic was about to get rather interesting with 2 or 3 diverging opinions... :)

Comment: Mowing the backyard can be fun, too (if the weather is nice) :)  Please take your time, I also need to work through the formalism first...especially how you and also @fulis represent a *finite* extinction ratio. Depolarization could also be an issue, see e.g. https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.48.3184

Comment: @EdV Sorry, didn't realize the paywall...the depolarization article is also on SciHub: https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/10.1103/physreve.48.3184

Comment: From the description of the problem you only know what the powers of the 2 states of linear(?) polarization is, and not their relative phase.  So any solution has to include this.

Comment: @EdV Good lord! I don't care about stupid downvotes from haters (I just neutralized it and will accept your answer shortly)...but don't you dare delete your excellent answer! That would be an utter loss. :) I'm working through it right now - it's a very thorough discussion - but I also have full lab days of work, so I need to read/learn during evening hours. Sorry for that...

Comment: ...plus, I had a few tiny questions for you, e.g. 1.) why [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfBv7.jpg) the degree of polarization is zero (and not one) after polarizers C, D, and E, and 2.) what the $a$ and $e$ indices [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Clh.jpg) mean in your notation of the Stokes vector sinks.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is nice to know that **making a sincere attempt to answer the actual question posed by the OP** is of some positive value! So, first, that degree of polarization just rounded off to zero due to double precision. And the little a and e at the bottom of the block refer to the azimuth and ellipticity. All 4 Stokes vector values and a and e are available as outputs for every simulation step in a multi-step time evolution simulation. In the figures, I just “turned off” display of the input and output connectors because it looks better to me, like a simple block diagram.

Comment: If you look at the dialog box of the Stokes vector sink block, there is a checkbox that, when checked, lets the block send out all 6 values for every sim time step. There was no need to run a sim longer than 1 step, but I always use 2, i.e., first and last step, for sims that are static. By the way, I used the monochromatic version of my software and selected Mueller calculus, it also does Jones calculus. And my polychromatic version can handle 100001 different wavelengths or wavenumbers, for either optical calculus. The optical vector formats are at one of the links I gave. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, I thank you! And also all other contributors (including @fulis for his demonstration using ket notation)...it's become clear that there is much more to a seemingly simple optical element such as a polarizer than one would initially expect. I still need to go through everything in detail to arrive at a final conclusion for myself and the problem I'm dealing with, without feeling like neglecting some of the information provided...will probably give a bit more feedback then. By the way: Shouldn't the degree of polarization be rounded to one ($0.9999998 < 0.999999999998 < 1$)?

Comment: Good point! I will check it, but my guess is that the light intensity was just too small. I also ran the model with all extinction ratios equal to 0.01, which is actually informative. I will check that one too and post a comment. At some point, the great machine will dump all comments to chat. We are probably right at the threshold …

Comment: ...indeed we are! ^^

Comment: ER doesn't matter for this.  The state of polarization (SOP) is well defined.  You can measure were it on the Poincare sphere.  If you don't like where it is, you're free to adjust it.  You've artificially chosen a linear SOP as some preferred basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP requests a formal proof, using Stokes vector and Mueller calculus formalism, as to whether stacking polarizers either does (or does not) *theoretically* improve the extinction ratio of a light source, e.g., a laser diode. Issues arising in practice, such as light scattering, reflection at interfaces, polarizer imperfections, depolarization, and so on, are to be neglected.

To begin, figure 1 shows the posited optical component train and the relevant Mueller calculus calculation that would be used to compute (manually) the output Stokes vector at G:

[image: Model and Mueller calculus computation]

The manual computation is straightforward, albeit a bit tedious, once the Mueller matrices for the linear polarizers have their requisite x and y transmittances specified. This is discussed below, in connection with the extinction ratio, $\epsilon$.

Now consider figure 2, which shows the assumed Mueller matrix for the linear polarizers and the dialog box for the polarizer block in [my optical calculus software](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/666241/313612) used to perform the non-manual computations:

[image: Polarizer Mueller matrix and dialog box]

The polarizer Mueller matrix is that of an ideal linear dichroism optical element. It is widely used to model ideal linear polarizer optical elements, as per Shurcliff, Kliger et al., and Jensen et al. As a convenience, two addendum figures, after the references, explicitly show the matrices used by the listed authors.

Note that the software polarizer block, that evaluates the polarizer’s Mueller matrix, allows for user-specification of the x and y transmittances. It also has a convenience checkbox that can be used to render the block transparent, i.e, the block then would simply transmit through whatever input it received. This facilitates trial removal of inline optical components.

Figure 3 shows how the laser light source is modeled as a unit intensity unpolarized Stokes vector followed by a non-ideal x-oriented linear polarizer having extinction ratio, $\epsilon$, defined as shown in the figure. This definition, which will be used throughout what follows, has long been in common usage and is found in, e.g., the reference by Kliger et al. on page 30. Note that $\epsilon$ ranges from 0, for an ideal polarizer, to 1, for non-polarizing. In the laser model, the non-ideal x polarizer was used to produce an output Stokes vector with $\epsilon = 0.01$, as explained below. The remaining blocks simply verify that the $\epsilon$ value is as specified. This is done by processing the laser output Stokes vector through orthogonal ideal analyzers and calculating the quotient of the light intensities they transmit.

[image: Laser source model]

It is also common to define $\epsilon$ as the reciprocal quantity, as per the link proved by the OP. Accordingly, such extinction ratios range from 1, for non-polarizing, to infinity, for an ideal polarizer. This alternative definition will not be used herein.

The figure shows how the model of the laser is formulated and processed via optical calculus modeling software. The output of the laser is shown in the software’s Stokes vector sink dialog box. The exact Stokes vector of the laser output is shown to the left of the dialog box. It is easily calculated manually, as shown in the Mueller calculus expressions in figure 4:

[image: Manual Mueller calculus computation]

The figure shows that obtaining a given $\epsilon$ is simply a matter of specifying a y component intensity that is $\epsilon$ times the intensity of the x component of the non-ideal x polarizer. With x + y = 1 and $\epsilon = 0.01$, this yields x = 100/101 and y = 1/101. The laser output Stokes vector is used in all subsequent calculations.

The degree of polarization, P, is a measure of polarization purity. It ranges from 0, for unpolarized light, to unity, for perfectly polarized light. The laser output Stokes vector has P = 99/101, as shown in the figure.

With the above preliminaries out of the way, the question is now this: what will happen to the degree of polarization if 1, 2, or 3 good polarizers (i.e., all with $\epsilon = 0.00001$) are added after the light source in an attempt to improve the polarization of the light source?

To answer this, consider figure 5:

[image: Measurement protocol]

To perform the optical calculus computation via the software, all that is necessary is to add another Stokes vector sink at the output of polarizer E. Then the simulation is run multiple times, with polarizer D (or both D and E) made transparent via their respective dialog box checkboxes.

The results are shown in figure 5. After polarizer C, the degree of polarization is high and the intensity of y polarized light is very low. Adding one or two more polarizers has only a very small positive effect. **The effects are so small as to be negligible.**

In a real system, a variety of non-idealities usually exist and these often cause significant departures from idealized modeled behavior. Mueller matrices (and Jones matrices) have demonstrated their utility, effectiveness and value over many decades, but they cannot perfectly model real optical elements such as polarizers. In particular, these calculuses assume individual light rays, **not** bundles of light rays. So they require homogeneous optical media. The typical tabulated matrices neglect scattering, reflections, depolarization, and so on, that real optical media exhibit. It is always possible to construct ever more complex matrices and models, in an attempt to achieve maximum verisimilitude, but this is ultimately futile, for two reasons:

1. As statistician George Box famously stated, in slightly variant ways over the years, “[all models are wrong, but some models are useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong).”
2. The [Bonini paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonini%27s_paradox)       arises: the more complicated the model is made, the less understandable it becomes.

So it is futile, in general, to try to make a grand “everything plus the kitchen sink” optical calculus matrix. A more productive route is to size up the various complexities and deal with the most relevant of them, neglecting the rest.

**References for the Mueller matrices for the ideal and non-ideal x polarizers:**

1. H.P. Jensen, J.A. Schellman, T. Troxell, “Modulation Techniques in Polarization Spectroscopy”, Applied Spectroscopy, 32 (1978) 192-200. Table IV with only LD > 0. (LD stands for linear dichroism, as used in the paper.)
2. W.A. Shurcliff, Polarized Light, Harvard University Press, Cambridge, MA, 1962. Page 166 for ideal polarizers and page 168 for “Other polarizers”.
3. D.S. Kliger, J.W. Lewis, C.E. Randall, “Polarized Light in Optics and Spectroscopy”, 1st ed., Academic Press, Boston, MA, 1990. Page 285 for ideal polarizers and page 290 for Linear Dichroism matrices.

**Addendum figures:**

[image: Shurcliff and Kliger et al. matrices]

and

[image: Jensen et al. matrices]

Comment: [This](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/36194) is for questions but it also applies to answers and your post in particular.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero In this case, I would accept the text-containing figures. The only figure where typesetting wouldn't involve too much work are the two bullet points in fig. 5. The rest is either mostly equations/formulae (which IMHO nobody is going to search for), figures reused from older answers, or screenshots from publications, which are already referenced and can be downloaded and searched.

Comment: @srhslvmn with due respect: you are free to accept what you like but for the benefit of the community and users at large, having a searchable website and taking time to reflect on a question or an answer so it is something more than what can be cut-and-pasted from another source are considered important for this community.  Clearly the vote outcomes of both the linked questions and multiple answers leaves no doubt about this.

Comment: @srhslvmn You might want to copy the whole answer, just in case it vanishes away, softly and suddenly, like the snark hunter. (The P value was actually 1, not 0. Just a typo when I copied the numbers.)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I get your point in general, but you cannot expect to typeset entire passages from papers, especially when they are fully referenced for the interested reader. There is a tipping point here between losing great answers vs. insisting on typesetting for some rather hypothetical edge cases and it's definitely not in the community's interest to err too much on the losing side. Which figure (except fig. 5) should be manually typed and why? Certainly not *all* of them? Also, do you really expect anyone to search SE for $\tfrac{x+y}{2}$ instead of *"Müller/Mueller matrix/matrices"*?

Comment: ...everyone uses a different notation, different variable names, maybe a different LaTeX command for an equation. Who in their right mind would search for one specific instance of a typeset equation instead of terms specific for the topic? What if the author used $\tfrac{a+b}{2}$ instead? Also, have a look at my search tags: *"electromagnetism, optics, laser, polarization, calculus"*

Comment: @srhslvmn people don’t search for LaTeX commands.  Search engines are smart enough to recognize characters in text but don’t so so well with characters as part of images.  Remember: what makes this site interesting is not what *you* get out of your question, but what the community at large gets out of good answers.  If they can’t find good answers then this simply becomes a collection of individual Q&A sessions.

Comment: @EdV Do you think it's time for an *Optics and Photonics SE* proposal in Area 51? Asking and answering those questions here often feels like an uphill battle, and in my opinion *Physics SE is too big!* [1](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12734/83380), [2](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14060/83380).

Comment: I have no idea what such a proposal would entail, but an Optics and Photonics SE, with a side of Spectroscopy friendliness, would be very welcome. Especially if it was more freeform, like your scenario of walking down the hall, grabbing a piece of **good** chalk, and start writing/drawing, etc. Like a saying (probably translated from the original Chinese) that I read long ago: “It is good to rub and polish one’s mind against those of others”.

Comment: +1 for Optics/Photonics/Spectroscopy SE. About time!

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Okay, my understanding of the search engine is insufficient to comment on this. Of course, you could adopt automated OCR, probably the easiest way to make screenshots of publications text-searchable!

Answer (score 2):

I will borrow the formalism of qubit states instead of using Mueller matrices, because it is a more convenient way to do calculations. Instead of describing the polarization using a four-component vector

$$
S = \begin{bmatrix}
S_0\\S_1\\S_2\\S_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
one uses a two-by-two matrix:

$$
\rho_S = \frac{1}{2}(S_0 I + S_1\sigma_x + S_2\sigma_y + S_1\sigma_z)
$$

where $\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z$ are the Pauli matrices. Intensity-normalized horizontally and vertically polarized states can be written

$$
|H\rangle\langle H|, \quad |V\rangle\langle V| 
$$

with

$$
|H\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
|V\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and an unpolarized state can be written
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2}I = \frac{1}{2}(|H\rangle\langle H| + |V\rangle\langle V|).
$$

An ideal polarizer corresponds to a projection onto a specific polarization, for example a vertical polarizer would simply be

$$
P_V = |V\rangle\langle V|,
$$

and polarizer with a finite extinction ratio can be written as a projection onto a partially polarized state

$$
P = a|H\rangle\langle H| + b|V\rangle\langle V|.
$$
If we initially have an unpolarized state, then the state after such a polarizer is

$$
P\rho = \frac{1}{2}(a|H\rangle\langle H| + b|V\rangle\langle V|)
$$
and the polarization extinction ratio is $\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|$ (assuming $a>b$).

Passing the state through a second identical polarizer results in the state

$$
P^2\rho =
\frac{1}{2}(a^2|H\rangle\langle H| + b^2|V\rangle\langle V|)
$$
with extinction ratio $\left|\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right|$, which again assuming $a>b$ is greater than the ratio achieved using only one polarizer.

Using this *model* of a non-ideal polarizer we get the results that stacking polarizers does improve the extinction ratio. However, it is very possible for a physical device to introduce some amount of depolarization, and in that case the above model is not a good description of the polarizer anymore, and sequential polarizers could never improve the extinction ratio above the limit set by the induced depolarization. In my personal experience, combining two relatively low ER polarizers (say 1000:1) can improve the extinction ratio, but this ceases to be useful for polarizers with very high extinction ratios. You also have the practical problem of simply aligning the axes of these polarizers well enough for such an exercise to be useful even in an ideal case.

Comment: Over-thinking, too abstract. With only linear polarization in play, you only have two components. With the polarizers assumed to be aligned, those two are independent.

Comment: Could you try to make a more coherent point?

Comment: What do you mean by more coherent?

Comment: (+1) Good answer and I especially liked the final paragraph. The devil is always in the details.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is ignoring the reality of the situation.  The extinction ratio of a given polarizer is usually limited by stress induced birefringence, or some other defect.

So, if I have a polarizer (doesn't matter which) with an ER of 100:1, and transmit a light source with an ER of 100:1, the result will still be 100:1 because some of the light polarized in the "100" direction will be rotated into the "1" axis due to the defect.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But please consider that I already had precisely this discussion with basically different opinions and explanations...which is the motivation to post this question in the first place: To get a definite answer from theory (and then discuss limiting effects such as depolarization, scattering on defects, stress-induced birefringence etc. as needed)

Comment: There's nothing fundamental about polarization that wouldn't let you achieve a perfect state of polarization.    In fact, if you had a 100:1 ER represents a state of perfect polarization.  Using a polarimeter you may achieve any other polarization state.

Comment: (+1) Your statement about stress induced birefringence brought back a not so pleasant memory of finding out the hard way that sapphire windows are not so good around 4 kelvin.

Comment: Birefringence by itself doesn't affect the degree of polarization, it just rotates the state of polarization. Linear loss cannot induce depolarization either. Spatial non-uniformities, however, are a contributor to a lower degree of polarization, because in detection you average over the whole transverse profile of the beam. Ultimately, whether or not stacking polarizers improves the degree of polarization is situation dependent, but it is possible and I've personally observed it.

Comment: Birefringence, in general, will move the state of polarization from one point on the Poincare sphere to another.   If you add a random variable, spatially or temporally, then, while there is an always a definite state of polarization, the description on the Poincare sphere may be a time-varying distribution.